# transform function in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I was reading the official documentation of PySpark API reference for dataframe and below code snippet for transform function over a dataframe have me confused. I can't figure out why * is placed before sorted function in sort_columns_asc function defined below

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1.0), (2, 2.0)], ["int", "float"])
def cast_all_to_int(input_df):
    return input_df.select([col(col_name).cast("int") for col_name in input_df.columns])
def sort_columns_asc(input_df):
    return input_df.select(*sorted(input_df.columns))
df.transform(cast_all_to_int).transform(sort_columns_asc).show()
+-----+---+
|float|int|
+-----+---+
|    1|  1|
|    2|  2|
+-----+---+
```

Please help me clarify the confusion.

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-and-doublestar-operator-mean-in-a-function-call

Comment: the aforementioned link will absolutely help you understand it. helpful note - before you step there, just understand what would that `df.columns` and `sorted()` result in.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used to unpack arrays/collections from a higher dimension.

```
# 1D Array
collection1 = [1,2,3,4]
print(*collection1)
1 2 3 4

# 2D Array
collection2 = [[1,2,3,4]]
print(*collection2)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

In your example you are unpacking the names of the column names from

```
example = ["int", "float"]
```

to

```
print(*sorted(example))
float int
```

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-and-doublestar-operator-mean-in-a-function-call) for further information.